# Change language directory without redirecting to the index page

Tags: php, file, chdir

I have a site in three languages:

```
 www.mysite.com/it/FILES
 www.mysite.com/de/FILES
 www.mysite.com/fr/FILES
```

On the header of the site I have three link, one for each language.
Each link redirect to

```
/language/index.php
```

I'd like to redirect the user to the current page he is watching but in the new language.

I tried with

```
__FILE__
```

or

```
dirname
```

but I didn't reach that!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the page your load:

```
$prefix = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$file = explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$page = $file[count($file)-1];

if (file_exists($prefix.'/it/'.$page)) {
    http_redirect($prefix.'/it/'.$page); // For Italian
}

if (file_exists($prefix.'/de/'.$page)) {
    http_redirect($prefix.'/de/'.$page); // For German
}

if (file_exists($prefix.'/fr/'.$page)) {
    http_redirect($prefix.'/fr/'.$page); // For French
}
```

In JavaScript (jQuery click example) you would do something like this:

```
var host = document.location.hostname;
var path = window.location.href;
var filename = path.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

$('.myItalianLink').click(function(){
    window.location.href = host + '/it/' + filename; // For Italian
});

console.log(host + '/it/' + filename);
```

Outputs:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/it/html4.php
```

The JavaScript approach will likely be more suiting for your needs, as it's more reactive in case of user interaction (the links you named).

Comment: so you suggest me to you jquery? With the php solution, I have a problem: the redirect is always to /it/it/page or /de/de/page or /fr/fr/page because the language is include in $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']

Comment: Not per se, you can just use a normal JavaScript onClick too. But you are expecting user input. It's nicer to do that client-side. You could do a new PHP request + a redirect too, but in your case it's a usability question, and does not incur security risk.

Comment: @user2120569 my bad; I've updated the code to use `$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`. This code will give you all PHP's server variables: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_COOKIE); print_r($_ENV); print_r($_FILES); print_r($_GET); print_r($_POST); print_r($_REQUEST); print_r($_SERVER); print_r($_SESSION); echo '</pre>';` (`$_SESSION` can be non-existent and some are empty when not used, like `$_POST`).

Comment: with $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] is the same. I think I'll use something like a function($lang) with str_replace and simply replace on the current url /it/ with /de/ or /fr/ and vice versa.

Comment: I've updated the answer. It should work now. I would recommend you use JavaScript for this situation tho.

Comment: I deleted one host, otherwise it was redirecting two times at the web site.
var host = document.location.hostname;
 var path = window.location.href;
 var filename = path.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
 
 $('#ted').click(function(){
  window.location.href = '/de/' + filename; // For German
 });

 console.log('/de/' + filename);